# get the source code of the newly customized data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

is there any way to get the source code of the newly customized data type?
After sometime, I forgot the meaning of the newly created data type...

```
postgres=# \dT+ twoints
                                        List of data types
 Schema |  Name   | Internal name | Size  | Elements |  Owner   | Access privileges | Description
--------+---------+---------------+-------+----------+----------+-------------------+-------------
 public | twoints | twoints       | tuple |          | postgres |                   |
```

`\dT+` seems don't give much info about the customized data type...

Also tried the  `pg_type` catelog.
[image]

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html

> typinput regproc (references pg_proc.oid)
>
> Input conversion function (text format)

maybe `typinput` can help me, but I don't know.

Comment: With only  "built-in" tools, you have to use `pg_dump`

Comment: Look at `pg_type`, it contains the definition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, pg_type give me more meta info. but there still not have the definition of newly created data type.

Comment: Sure, it is all there. That is all that PostgreSQL knows about your type, except 1) if it is a composite type, `pg_attribute` will have more and 2) if it is an enum, `pg_enum` will hold details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

through **pgadmin4**.

databases >> postgres >> schema >> Types >> twoints, right click ***CREATE Script***